# Apache2 just points to global documentRoot instead of document root for subdomain

Tags: apache, apache2, web-hosting

##### The problem I am having is:

- I am trying to set up apache2 to redirect readerlol.chaimstanton.co.uk to the directory `/var/www/html/readerlol.chaimstanton.co.uk` however when you go to that address you get this
  [image: Index of / then lists the directories there]
  Which just points to the root directory

##### What I am trying to achieve

- When someone goes to readerlol.chaimstanton.co.uk it should open the `index.html` in `/var/www/html/readerlol.chaimstanton.co.uk`

##### My setup

- A Droplet in Digital Ocean using the LAMP default image. Running Ubuntu
- SSH'ing into the command line of the server

##### Things I've tried

- Stopping and starting apache2 service
- Rebooting the server
- Checking the filename in apache2.conf against the file name
- Changing the document root for the virtual host to `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/readerlol.chaimstanton.co.uk/index.html`
- I have tried disabling SSL

##### Log stuff

- My apache2.conf file is [this](https://gist.github.com/ChaimStanton/90c8d4bab1739d1b1e1f0ed37c8d893f) or just the end virtual host part [here](https://gist.github.com/ChaimStanton/4213e7f4568590b24f24f55f63069674)
- `apachectl configtest` returns `Syntax OK`
- `apachectl -S` returns [this](https://gist.github.com/ChaimStanton/49c8238fe975cdd98ebceb8ea0d7f6f4)
- The full text of the `error.log` file is [here](https://gist.github.com/ChaimStanton/05967dfeb7f2c1ec850bdec73c8ead0d)

NOTE: I figured webmasters might not be the best place for this so I've put it here.

Answer (score 0):

Subdomains require an additional site within apache.
Make sure you added another site to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`
Have you already configured you DNS to point to your server?

Comment: I have already configured the DNS pointed to my server.

Comment: How would I add another site to the sites-enabled folder? Also, I don't see why I would need to add a site to there when I already have two subDomains that don't need to be mentioned in that folder.